# Which libraries are used in this site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a site using the "technology" of this one:

http://www.domperignon.com/

But I don't know where to find something like this...

Thanks in advance,
DGM.-

Comment: It's Wordpress with what look like a few custom scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Chrome or Firefox, you can inspect the site. For Chrome, right click anywhere on the site and hit Inspect Element. For Firefox, you need to download an add-on called Firebug.

For Chrome, a pop-up should appear with several tabs and showing the source code for the html website. You can peruse through that if you want but I believe the "technology" you are referring to is more or less located in their javascript files.

Click the Resources tab and the first folder says Frames. Click it and you should see all of their files including js files, images, stylesheets, etc.

If you are using Firefox Firebug, right click anywhere on the page and hit Inspect Element with Firebug. The tabs on the top separate it nicely for you so you can just go straight to Scripts, CSS, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bookmarklet to determine which scripts are running on a page:

```
javascript:(function(){s=document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');tx='';sr=[];for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){with(s.item(i)){t=text;if(t){tx+=t;}else{sr.push(src)};}};with(window.open()){document.write('<textarea id="t">'+(sr.join("\n"))+"\n\n-----\n\n"+tx+'</textarea><script src="http://jsbeautifier.org/beautify.js"></script><script>with(document.getElementById("t")){value=js_beautify(value);with(style){width="99%";height="99%";borderStyle="none";}};</script>');document.close();}})();
```

Just save it as a bookmark and run it on any page.

Comment: i think this is developed in wordpress